# Image in table cell without margin

Tags: tables, spacing, graphics, size

I want to make a table with images inside, which fit perfectly within the lines. This was my solution to it:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
   \includegraphics[height=.05\textwidth]{IMG_Temp} &
   \includegraphics[height=.05\textwidth]{IMG_Temp} \\
\hline
   1 & 2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Text.}
\label{tab:table}
\end{table}
```

[image: table showing images with white gaps]

I figured out that by adding `@{}` like this: `\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|}`, I get rid of the horizontal margin.

[image: table showing images with no gaps at side but gap at bottom]

However, there is still a little gap beneath the image. How I can remove this margin?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also nobody except you can access `IMG_Temp`. You can use `example-image-duck` instead.

Comment: How about just eliminating the `\hline` directive below the graphs? No one will be the wiser, and no one will care.

Comment: @Mico Some people do care! At some places it is placed here using a, corporate, style and I think here the hline serves as an example but could also be something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `valign` key provided by `adjustbox` with the `export` option does give the desired result (funny enough not depending on the value given to the key). This only works if the image's vertical dimensions are larger than `\baselineskip` in total.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[]{|@{}c@{}|}
  \hline
  \includegraphics[height=.05\textheight,valign=b]{example-image-duck}\\
  \hline
  next line\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]